# Sorting images in table in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, formula, table

I have a text formula field (Star_Rating__c) to show star rating using images

```
    IMAGE(IF(ISPICKVAL(Rating__c,"1 Star"), "/img/samples/stars_100.gif",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Rating__c,"2 Star"), "/img/samples/stars_200.gif",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Rating__c,"3 Star"), "/img/samples/stars_300.gif",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Rating__c,"4 Star"), "/img/samples/stars_400.gif",
IF(ISPICKVAL(Rating__c,"5 Star"), "/img/samples/stars_500.gif", "/img/samples/stars_000.gif"
))))),
"")
```

I am pulling this formula in my visualforce page table as below:

```
<table id="jobApplicantTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%"> 
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                             <th>Star Rating</th>
                         </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody> 
                        <apex:repeat value="{!jobApplicantList}" var="jobApplicant">
                             <tr> 
                                 <td><apex:outputLabel escape="false" value="{!jobApplicant.Star_Rating__c}"></apex:outputLabel></td>
                             </tr>
                         </apex:repeat>
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
```

Problem is its not sorting in visualforce page. Anyone know any solution?
When i checked same field in standard list view it sorts perfectly.... :( but not in my visualforce page.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a basic sorting by using the `ORDER BY`clause of SOQL

```
SELECT Id from Custom_Object__c ORDER BY Rating__c DESC
```

This will get you the records sorted in one direction or the other (DESC being highest rated first).

If you want to apply dynamic sorting to the table so that when a user clicks the table header the table automatically sorts, you're going to have a MUCH harder time. I usually use [jQuery Data Tables](https://datatables.net/).

### Disclaimer

This is not a JS website and as such we will only provide minimal JS support as it specifically pertains to SF. If you want advanced features as obtained through JS you'll have to ask questions on https://StackOverflow.com.

Comment: My line is very specific, even if I didn't particularly articulate it in my prior comment. Here's how I view it: if you could remove all the Visualforce, make minimal modifications, and it would be a good fit for [so], then it's not a Visualforce question (e.g. your SPA example). Contrariwise, if you removed all the Visualforce, made minimal modifications, and the problem is unreproduceable or goes away, it belongs here. Yes, we don't support random JavaScript, but we do if it's on-topic. Your edit is much better.

Comment: I completely agree with your statement :)

Comment: @gNerb I was aware of SOQL sorting  but what i needed was your second suggestion about sorting data tables using jquery.  I searched on it and i found boostrap dataTable sort option which works great